# Kubernetes Ingress redirect of Express.js /public folder

Tags: node.js, express, kubernetes

I've been reading the past few days on how to do this, tried server-snippets and didn't work (or I did it wrong).  Anyway, I would like to have my Ingress for my QA & Prod clusters redirect calls to my public folder in Express.js to my CDN instead of the local folders (/js, /css, /images, etc).

i.e. https://www.example.com/js/all.js -> https://cdn.example.com/assets/js/all.js

Has anyone done this with success and would like to give me some pointers?

Comment: Try https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/nginx-configuration/annotations/#custom-nginx-upstream-vhost if you are using nginx controller

Comment: Can you clarify which `Ingress` controller are you using? Did the link that Ken Chen provided helped you?

Comment: The standard Ingress Controller and his comment does not help as that redirects all, I just want to redirect specific folders in a deployment.

Comment: What do you mean by standard Ingress controller? Does your Kubernetes cluster is a managed solution like `GKE`,`EKS` or `AKS`? I think this can be done with `Nginx Ingress` controller with addition of `VirtualServer` CRD's. Please take a look here: [Docs.nginx.com: Nginx-Ingress: VirtualServer and VirtualServerRoutes](https://docs.nginx.com/nginx-ingress-controller/configuration/virtualserver-and-virtualserverroute-resources/)

Comment: I will look into that some then, I went the route of just doing it all in Express.js right now for routing since I couldn't find the solution I wanted.

Comment: I'm glad that you resolved it. If you are willing please share how you've managed to do it with Express.js as other community members should benefit from that.

Answer (score -1):

This is not how CDNs work. If the traffic reaches your backend it is already "too late" for CDNs. Your static assets must be delivered *directly* via your CDN. Only non-static page requests, REST-API calls and Websocket connections should make it to your cluster.

What you have to do now is pretty simple. Inside your (generated) HTML, replace the URLs to your assets that point to your own server with the ones pointing to your CDN.
E.g. the following:

```html
<script type='text/javascript' src='https://www.example.com/js/all.js'></script>
```

becomes:

```html
<script type='text/javascript' src='https://cdn.example.com/js/all.js'></script>
```

***In fact***, your own server **must** respond to calls to your assets (e.g. /js, /css, /images, ...) with its own local resources in order to let your CDN fetch and cache the resources properly. Redirecting traffic would probably break your CDNs caching mechanisms.

Comment: Hi, not sure if you understood my question.  I know how generic CDNs work, that's not my question.  This is a Kubernets ingress question on handling traffic flow.

Comment: I understood your question, but what you are trying to achieve does not make any sense. If you route the call to your cluster/server, why would you then issue a redirect or worse proxy the call to an external mirror? In any other case (if you use https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/) you can just add the "nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/configuration-snippet" annotation and write a redirect or return statement.